# Generalization of Lines and Planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be constants that are not all zero.

An equation defines a line if and only if it can be written:
$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3=0$

An equation defines a plane if and only if it can be written:
$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4=0$

What does this define?
$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4+a_5=0$

Is there a name for the class of objects these equations define?

Comment: I believe one name for it is a 3-hyperplane in $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ .  All of the nice things you learn about in linear algebra can be extended to as (finitely) many dimensions as you may wish...

Comment: It's called a hyperplane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at least one of $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$ is nonzero and $a_{n+1}$ is fixed, then the set
$$
\{(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n:a_1x_1+\dotsb+a_nx_n+a_{n+1}=0\}
$$
is called an **affine hyperplane of dimension $n$**.

More generally, if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) $k$ and $\vec a_0\in\Bbb R^m$, then the set
$$
\{\vec x\in\Bbb R^n:A\vec x+\vec a_o=\vec 0\}
$$
is an **affine linear subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ of dimension $n-k$** or an **affine linear subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ of codimension $k$**.

Of course, if $\vec a_0=\vec 0$, then we drop the word "affine".